# "copy web service method must be called on the same domain that contains the destination url"

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-services

I am trying to upload document from physical location to SharePoint.

Documents and SharePoint server are different. I am using `copy.asmx` service to upload document. But while uploading I am getting following error:

> Copy web service method must be called on the same domain that contains the destination url

Not sure why I am getting this error. I test it by placing document on same SharePointserver but same error.

I have done the same task before. I have copied many documents. But this time I am facing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Copy.asmx service is for copying files from one SharePoint site to other. Its not for copying data from a physical location to SharePoint. Check this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/copy(v=office.12).aspx